# setInterval and setTimeout do not work in react-native / android / genymotion

Tags: android, react-native, settimeout, setinterval, genymotion

I am running a react-native application built for android (on a Windows 10 PC), and setTimeout and setInterval did not work.

I searched the web for a solution, didn't find any, and after losing two hours on useless trials, decided to restart the emulator. This solved the problem.

This happened several weeks ago.
Today I came into this problem again, and decided to write this question and answer it, in order to save time for you :), if you have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is written in the question: just restart the emulator.